# How do I get rid of the elif syntax error on my UpdateCursor?

Tags: python, math, syntax, arcgis, arcpy

Why am I getting a Syntax error on elif when trying to calculate an index with the UpdateCursor function in Python? This is my code, the second elif always gives a syntax error.

```
    fc = 'Oberbodenproben_mit_Laborwerten_2019_1'
    fields = ['ABAG_K_Faktor','K1','K2','K3','T_proz','U_proz','S_proz','U+ffS_proz','S-ffS_proz','Org_Substanz_proz','Permeabilitätsklasse','Aggregierungsklasse','Steinbedeckung_proz']
```

## Create update cursor for feature class

```
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
        
# For each row, evaluate the WELL_YIELD value (index position 
# of 0), and update WELL_CLASS (index position of 1)

       for row in cursor:   

         if (row[7]<= 70):
           row[1] = 2.77*10**(-5) *((row[7]*(100-row[4]))**1.14
         elif(row[7] > 70):
           row[1] = 1.75*10**(-5)*((row[7]*(100-row[4]))**1.14+0.0024*row[8]+0,161
         elif (row[9] <= 4):
           row[2] = row[1]*(12-row[9])/10
         elif (row[9] > 4):
           row[2] = row[1]*0.8
         elif (row[2] >= 0.2):
           row[3] = row[2]+0.043*(row[11]-2)+0.033*(4-row[10])
         elif (row[2] < 0.2):
           row[3] = 0.091-0.34*row[2]+1.79*row[2]**2+0.24*row[2]*row[11]+0.033*(4-row[10])   
         elif (row[12]<=1,5):
           row[0]=row[3]
         elif (row[12]>1,5):
           row[0]=row[3]*(1.1*math.e**(-0.0024*row[12])-0.06)
               
    # Update the cursor with the updated list
    cursor.updateRow(row)

    return
```

I already tried getting read of the formulas, but with easy numbers another problem turns up. Apparently the rows don't exist then.

Comment: Looks like a missing `)` in the `row[1] = 1.75...` line.  What is the full traceback of the error?  Not sure why you have commas in some lines as well.  Python doesn't understand commas for decimal points if that's what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Indents matter for python code.
And so do matching `(` `)` parens.
Here is what you intended:

```
    for row in cursor:

        if row[7] <= 70:
            row[1] = 2.77 * 10 ** (-5) * ((row[7] * (100 - row[4])) ** 1.14)
        elif row[7] > 70:
            row[1] = (
                1.75
                * 10 ** (-5)
                * ((row[7] * (100 - row[4])) ** 1.14 + 0.0024 * row[8] + 0, 161)
            )
        elif row[9] <= 4:
            row[2] = row[1] * (12 - row[9]) / 10
        elif row[9] > 4:
            row[2] = row[1] * 0.8
        elif row[2] >= 0.2:
            row[3] = row[2] + 0.043 * (row[11] - 2) + 0.033 * (4 - row[10])
        elif row[2] < 0.2:
            row[3] = (
                0.091
                - 0.34 * row[2]
                + 1.79 * row[2] ** 2
                + 0.24 * row[2] * row[11]
                + 0.033 * (4 - row[10])
            )
        elif (row[12] <= 1, 5):
            row[0] = row[3]
        elif (row[12] > 1, 5):
            row[0] = row[3] * (1.1 * math.e ** (-0.0024 * row[12]) - 0.06)
```

`1.75 * 10 ** (-5)` is kind of a curious way
to express the constant `1.75e-5`, but I guess
it works for you so go for it.

---

Using the **name** of each field within a row
would be much more readable than indexes like `[12]`.

Consider doing

```
from collections import namedtuple`

Foo = namedtuple("Foo", fields)
```

(It's not yet clear what each row represents -- choose
a more descriptive name than Foo.)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple